# The ring of upper triangular matrices as a module over itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

$R$ is taken to be the ring of upper $3 \times 3$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$.

If I view $R$ as a module over itself, are any of its submodules free?

And how can I prove that its submodules are pojective $R$-modules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of its proper submodules could be free. Think about it: $R$ is a $6$ $\Bbb R$ dimensional algebra. It could not contain even a single copy of itself properly, considering that a single copy would have dimension at least $6$.

It certainly contains projective submodules, though. For any idempotent $e$, $eR$ is going to be a summand of $R$, and hence a projective module.

Actually triangular matrix rings over fields are [hereditary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditary_ring) meaning that all their left and right ideals are projective.

---

The only proofs I'm aware of for this would be a little long to write out. I know a proof appears in section 2 of *Lectures on Modules and Rings*, and *First Course in Noncommutative rings* section 25, both books by T.Y. Lam.

The version I like is the one where you show that a ring is right hereditary iff its Jacobson radical is a projective right $R$ module.

Comment: Thank you . great! but I still need to show why it's hereditary. Any hint?

Comment: I mean my definition of hereditary is that all left and right ideals are projective... So, I'm still facing the same problem :(

Comment: @CarlaB. You should really ask "how can I prove" rather than "can I know if" in the original question, then... I'll see what I can add.

Answer (score 1):

The algebra you're studying is the [path algebra](http://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~sek/kau/leit4.pdf) over the quiver
$$
\underset{1}{\bullet}\xrightarrow{\alpha}\underset{2}{\bullet}
\xrightarrow{\beta}\underset{3}{\bullet}
$$
so it's hereditary as all path algebras. You find a proof of this result in [a paper by C. M. Ringel](http://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~ringel/opus/ext2.pdf), see section 3, page 3.